# Mentioning authors name not using any \cite

Tags: citing

I want to mention author's name as in, "A and B showed that...." but don't want to use any \cite options primarily because "A and B" showed *that* through a series of work. What is the standard way of doing that like the last name and then initials? would appreciate any examples. Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. I think what you are looking for is `\citeauthor{citekey}`, which gives a `labelname` without year etc., which is what you probably want. In case you are using biblatex, which you should, see [biblatex manual](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) page 113.

Comment: @Celdor Thanks! `\citeauthor{authorkey}` will point to a specific work that I don't want. I literally want to mention the name of the authors not singling out specific work. Thanks again!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a LaTeX question then. Just use "Smith and Jones showed that ..." No initials needed (except perhaps in exceptional cases where you have multiple people with the same surname, in which case you might use "J. Smith and Jones showed that..."